# Feeds auto create is not working

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, feeds, importing-exporting

Am using [Drupal 7 Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module and I have "Autocomplete term widget (tagging)" field in content type.

As well as I have configured as "Auto create". But, when I import nodes that auto creation does not working, its shows the blank field.

Any other way to do?

Answer (score 0):

If Feeds creates empty values on *Auto create*, you need to verify your mapping. Make sure your *Context Value* in *XML Xpath parser* is fetching the right data by enabling *Debug* option, so you can see exact value being imported. If it's not, please validate your XPath on your sample data (for example, on [XPath Tester](http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester)).

If your XPath is correct, then use `hook_feeds_after_parse()` to debug your feed items.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_feeds_after_parse().
 * Invoked after a feed source has been parsed, before it will be processed.
 */
function MYMODULE_feeds_after_parse(FeedsSource $source, FeedsParserResult $result) {
  foreach ($result->items as &$item) {
    drupal_set_message(print_r($item, TRUE));
  }
}
```